# MSIE $.ajax delays in Heroku SSL Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer, heroku

We have a Rails 3 app on Heroku that is suffering from long delays on jQuery AJAX requests in IE11 in particular -- consistently about 4 or 5 seconds.  The requests aren't failing; they just take forever.  Civilized browsers like Chrome, FF & Safari all respond within a fraction of a second.  And I can see that the response times on the server are that fast, but IE takes 4-5 seconds to show the request is complete.

I've got a barebones app to demonstrate: https://ajax-testing.herokuapp.com/test.  Clicking the text sends the AJAX request to the server which echoes it back and it's shown in an alert.  I find it's quick in all browsers except IE, where you don't see the alert for 5 seconds.

I don't experience the delays when I'm testing locally, but when it's deployed to Heroku I do.  I've determined it has something to do with SSL on Heroku, because the problem goes away if I set config.force_ssl to false.  The only real difference in the headers between the SSL (with delays) and non-SSL (no delays) on Heroku is the Strict-Transport-Security header in the SSL version.

Here's the code for the AJAX request...

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_call",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { message: "Test message" }
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data["message"]);
  });
```

Setup:

- Rails 3.2.21 on Heroku
- jQuery 1.11.1
- Tried both thin & unicorn
- IE 11.0.9600.17633 (11.0.16 update)

I've tried different servers, taking out the dataType and other $.ajax variations, adding IE-specific meta tags, etc. I can't find any reference to this specific problem online.  Anyone have suggestions on what it could be or how to narrow it down further?

Comment: its better to write `data["message"]` as `data.message`. However there must be something else which is holding the request because from first look i did not see anything suspicious.

Comment: @greg, did you solve it? I have the exact same problem (ssl, heroku, Rails, ajax request), the only difference is that i use Rails 4.1

Comment: @ExiRe You mean I'm not alone?! I was amazed not to find an anyone else with this problem online when I was searching. I did find an answer -- it was somewhat drawn out getting it solved, so I hadn't gotten around to posting an answer. See below.

Comment: @Greg Thank God that you have found the answer!! I was stuck for a lot of hours without ANY result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a Heroku problem due to a bug in a recent load balancer update. I spent huge amounts of time pursuing it on the assumption that it was caused by a recent IE update, which coincided with the first reports of the problem, and since IE was the only browser affected in our tests.

When I saw problems with JavaScript execution, my first thought wasn't:  check the ELB -- but it probably should have been ;)  This is the first time we've had our apps break due to a Heroku/Amazon update.

Apparently, the problem occurs on requests that don't have `Content-Length` or `Transfer-encoding: chunked` headers and it may only affect certain stack configurations, or else I'd think I'd have been able to find more reports of it.

If you're experiencing this, create a help ticket and tell them you have IE latency in your app and you think it's due to the recent ELB update.  They can deploy an update to the ELB for your apps, which is what they ended up doing for us, and will eventually do for all Heroku apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. I created the ticket and hope that it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Rails with unicorn on Heroku with all pages under SSL.  They suggest setting `RACK_ENV=deployment` to force unicorn to load the `Rack::ContentLength` and `Rack::Chunked` middlewares (or manually add them yourself).  That fixed the problem for me without needing to have them deploy an update for my app specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this thread, we were very close to spending a lot of time on this. We'd just enabled Rack::Deflate but rolling that back hadn't resolved this. We are running under HTTPS as well.

Heroku's response was:

> We recently found out that it is because of Unicorn web server behavior + Heroku default RACK_ENV=production. You actually should use Unicorn with RACK_ENV=deployment (see https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn.rb#L56-L79 for more detail), or you should use Unicorn with HTTP servers such as nginx.
>
> Both of them solve the problem that you have now.
>
> This issue is happening because your response doesn't contain Content-Length header, nor Transfer-encoding: chunked. It is not invalid HTTP response, but it is not good HTTP response and you want to fix it.
>   You could also manually add the middleware such as Rack::ContentLength and/or Rack::Chunked.
>
> Alternatively, you can switch to Puma (https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn.rb#L56-L79 which is 
>   our recommended web server now).

I've added Rack::Chunked to get out of Dodge now. Rack::Deflate strips the contentLength header I believe.

I wasn't really aware of the RACK_ENV options, but [I'm not alone there](http://www.hezmatt.org/~mpalmer/blog/2013/10/13/rack_env-its-not-for-you.html)!

I guess updating RACK_ENV and migrating to Puma is the next step.

Comment: short answer: just set RACK_ENV=deployment and you're done as @jmichels outlines below